# Symmetry of Scalar Action Associated with (Conformal) Killing Tensor

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, action

**Short version:**

Consider the action for a scalar field coupled to the Ricci scalar in $d$ spacetime dimensions:

$$S = -\frac{1}{2}\int d^dx \, \left(\nabla_\mu \phi \nabla^\mu \phi + \xi R \phi^2\right).$$

If $K$ is a Killing vector, i.e., it satisfies
$$\nabla_\mu K_\nu + \nabla_\nu K_\mu = 0,$$
then the action is invariant under the following transformation:
$$\delta \phi = K^\mu \nabla_\mu \phi.$$
More generally, if $K$ is a conformal Killing vector, i.e., it satisfies
$$\nabla_\mu K_\nu + \nabla_\nu K_\mu = \frac{2}{d} \nabla^\lambda K_\lambda g_{\mu\nu},$$
and the scalar is conformally coupled ($\xi = \frac{d-2}{4(d-1)}$), then the action is invariant under the following more general transformation:
$$\delta \phi = K^\mu \nabla_\mu \phi + \frac{d-2}{2d} \nabla_\mu K^\mu \phi.$$
Now consider a conformal Killing tensor with $n$ indices, which is completely symmetric and satisfies
$$\nabla_{(\lambda}K_{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_n)} = g_{(\lambda \mu_1} P_{\mu_2 \mu_3 \cdots \mu_n)}$$
for some $(n-1)$-index tensor $P$. By taking various traces, we can express $P$ in terms of various derivatives of $K$. If $K$ is an ordinary Killing tensor, then $P = 0$.

**Is there a symmetry of the action associated with the conformal Killing tensor?**

**Longer version:**

I am interested in studying higher-spin symmetries for conformal field theories. These symmetries generalize the well-known result that given a stress-energy tensor which is a traceless on -shell and a conformal Killing vector, we can form the current
$$J_\mu = T_{\mu\nu} K^\nu,$$
which satisfies $\nabla_\mu J^\mu = 0$ on-shell. It follows that we have a conserved charge and thus a symmetry of the action for every conformal Killing vector. These charges correspond to the generators of the conformal group.

The generalization involves constructing an object
$$J_{\mu_1 \mu_2 \cdots \mu_s} 
= \sum_{k = 0}^s c_k \nabla_{\{\mu_1}\cdots\nabla_{\mu_k} \phi
\nabla_{\mu_{k+1}}\cdots\nabla_{\mu_n\}} \phi,$$
where the curly braces indicate traceless symmetrization. The coefficients $c_k$ are fixed by imposing
$$\nabla^{\mu_1} J_{\mu_1 \mu_2 \cdots \mu_s}  = 0$$
on-shell. Given a conformal Killing tensor with $s-1$ indices, we can construct a current
$$J_{\mu_1} = J_{\mu_1 \mu_2 \cdots \mu_s} K^{\mu_2 \cdots \mu_s},$$
which again will obey $\nabla_\mu J^\mu = 0$ on-shell.
The charge associated with this current corresponds to a symmetry of the action, i.e.
$$\{Q, \phi\} = \delta \phi,$$
where the braces represent the field-theoretic Poisson bracket and we again assume that the scalar is conformally coupled.

However, I cannot find any reference that explicitly gives this symmetry, even in the case of an ordinary Killing tensor with two indices. The best I have found is the following schematic expression:
$$\{Q, \phi\} \sim K^{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_{s-1}} 
\nabla_{\mu_1}\cdots\nabla_{\mu_{s-1}} \phi.$$
My guess is that in the simplest case of two indices, the transformation is something like
$$\{Q, \phi\} = K^{\mu_1 \mu_2} 
\nabla_{\mu_1}\nabla_{\mu_2}\phi 
+ \alpha \nabla_{\mu_1}\nabla_{\mu_2} K^{\mu_1 \mu_2} \phi,$$
where $\alpha$ is some numerical factor. **Is there a systematic way of deriving such a symmetry for a generic conformal Killing tensor?**